# Lubuntu won't shutdown

Tags: boot, system-installation, lubuntu, shutdown, macbook

As it will become obvious from this post, I am new to Linux and Ubuntu, I would thus be grateful if you could adjust the answers accordingly.

I just managed to successfully install Lubuntu 16.10 as the only OS in my old white Macbook (Core 2 Duo).

Although it is slow, it turns on nicely and the little I have tried, it seems to work fine. However, I can't turn it off. When I shutdown with the button, the computer is stuck in a screen that I can't understand and of which I have taken a picture from which you can read the messages.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

How can I fix this?

Maybe it is good to signal that my installation only succeeded after I ran boot-repair from a live USB. Otherwise I was hitting the error `grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install`.

Comment: Any peripheral devices connected while shutting down?

Comment: I presume the same thing happens if you run `sudo shutdown -h now`?